# PHP - accepting multiple payment gateways

Tags: php, paypal, e-commerce, payment-gateway, google-checkout

I am creating a site where I will be selling a single item and want to be able to accept payment through Paypal, Google Checkout and Amazon but don't want to use some heavy eCommerce software for just a single item.

I'm looking for a good PHP solution that will make it easy to implement all 3, something like Django-Merchant for Django.

Thanks

Comment: Can you not just implement these yourself? That way you can avoid much more 'heavyness' :) All of the above providers will have example code for PHP with their SDK downloads.

Comment: you would have a controller for each payment gateway then use the controller on which payment gateway the user chooses.

Answer (score 4):

If you are expecting an suggestion regarding Architectural Design of the solution,

First you need to create an interface with all the methods which are mandatory with all the gateways

```
interface PaymentGateway {
   public function processPayment();
   public function authorize();
}
```

then create concrete classes for each payment gateway

```
public class GoogleCheckoutGateway extends PaymentGateway {
     public function processPayment() {
        //Code to process google checkout payment
     }
}

//Same like other payment gateways like paypal
public class PaypalCheckoutGateway extends PaymentGateway {
     public function processPayment() {
        //Code to process paypal payment
     }
}
```

then create a Business Logic method to process payment by dealing with different gateways

```
public class PaymentProcessor {
     public function processPayment(string gateway) {
        //Create the respective object depending upon gateway
        $gateway = getGateway(type);
        $response = $gateway->processPayment();
     }
}
```

This design will help you add addtional gateways later

Comment: You can not extend interface. You can implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Single item for the foreseeable future? Each of those 3rd party checkout alternatives (just distinguishing the term *"gateway"* which has a different meaning when it comes to credit card payments) provides an API and sample code/SDK.

I think its good practice for you to look them up so you have "first hand" knowledge of how each work which will further help you down the road when its time to go for some software package - re: you can tinker to your needs and/or know how to deal with issues if/when they occur.

You *may* also find that whatever "order management interface" each provides is all you really need to use (re: *single item*) - a classic case of being caught between *developer and business owner hats* (know what you really want to do and/or accomplish).